# Replacing sync services Apple is dropping in iCloud

Tags: software-recommendation, data-synchronization, icloud

I have a two Macs at home and one at work that I have kept nicely synced with a combination of MobileMe and Jungle Disk. Apple's replacement for MobileMe, iCloud, looks interesting, but I am not going to switch until I have an adequate replacement for three [syncing services Apple is dropping](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4898).

- Mail Rule Syncing
- Preference Syncing
- Keychain Syncing

What are my options at present for replacing these services?

Answer (score 1):

You can sync your keychain with [Keychain2go](http://www.jinx.de/Keychain2Go.html)

Answer (score 0):

- Mail Rule Syncing: Developer (in this case Apple) needs to update the applications to use iCloud to synchronize preferences. It will happen slowly but surely since it's very convenient to users.
- Preference Syncing: See above.
- Keychain Syncing: I strongly recommend you don't sync your keychain, and instead use a more secure and complete solution. I very highly recommend 1Password. It will sync everything over iCloud but it's very secure, and it makes it very easy to have different randomly generated passwords for each and every site you use.

Comment: However MobileMe was removed several months ago - what do we use now. + many apps using preferences won't and should not use iCloud